# How can I automatically set an HTML attribute if missing, globally or per-domain?

Tags: google-chrome, script, html

Chrome automatically creates a tiny HTML page with a `<video>` tag to let you play MP3 files without manually downloading first.

It's very useful but no width/height attributes are set and the default size is so small the sliders are hard to use.

I can manually add a width attribute in Chrome dev-tools but is there a way to automate this either on any such `<video>` element or only on certain domains? No CSS styles are applied by Chrome in the generated pages.

Comment: And no I don't want to fork Chrome and build my own version :)

Comment: (not sure if there is a better SE site, I couldn't decide if this is development or power-user or something else)